# Is it possible to disassociate working memory and consciousness?

Tags: memory, consciousness

The traditional view holds that consciousness and working memory has linked tightly. But some researches have some proofs against this idea. The study said that people can reading and doing arithmetic nonconsciously [(Sklar et al., 2012)](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1211645109). Is that means there is a implicit working memory and we can manipulate the information in a short term, unconsciously?